# How would you describe the difference between 'thereto' and 'theretoward'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, differences

I would appreciate it if you may respond to or comment on the differences or applications of "thereto" and "theretoward" in modern writings or provide other single words that would be of similar use. 
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Neither word is "modern" and mostly found only in legal contexts. It's also expected you might take a peek at an online dictionary first to see if you can answer your question yourself.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Questions where no reasonable research has been provided (here, a few modern quotes containing the words, and Ngrams) are also off-topic. Most of the recent examples I've found involve legalese or quotes from old books.

Comment: theretoward is not a word in contemporary English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Can someone get rid of the hyphen in _commonly-available_? It's so overkill.

Comment: How would you use _to there_ and _toward there_? That's all they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both 'thereto' and 'theretoward' are archaic. They are hardly used at all in natural English speech or writing currently.

'Thereto' however is used often enough in legal writing:

> ["...providing, first, for the building or repairing of such ferries and the approaches thereto by contract..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=ehkntH8cU1AC&pg=PA38&q=%22thereto%22)

and acts as a pronoun for a prepositional phrase with 'to'. In modern English it could be replaced with 'to it'.

['Theretoward' is just not used.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thereto%2C+theretoward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) It's supposed meaning should be derivable as more specific than 'thereto' ('toward something' is more specific than 'to something') but it just doesn't occur in legal writings.

[image: google ngrams of thereto and theretoward]

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, but note that in your example *thereto* could only be replaced by *to them*, so it's not entirely straightforward.